# Equation of a line segment given a set

Tags: calculus, surface-integrals

Hi I'm trying to figure out how to do this question

$\ S={(x,y,z):x,y,z≥0, 2x+y+2z=4}, $
which is a surface in the first octant.

Find the equation of the line segment where S intersects the x-y plane. And then evaluate

$$\int_S (x +y + z) \;\mathrm{d}S $$

So I know that seeing as it's the xy-plane that means z = 0 so when I manipulate the equation to get y = 4-2x but I'm unsure how to do the rest especially the parameterisation (I'm quite new at this)

Help would be greatly appreciated

UPDATE : so I've found the points $\ (x, y, 2-x- \frac y2) $

when I differentiate this with respect to x I get $\ (1, 0, -1) $

when I differentiate this with respect to y I get $\ (0, 1,- \frac 12) $

if i take the cross product of both of these I get $\ (1, \frac 12, 1) $

So is that my answer?

Comment: What must z be on the xy plane?

Comment: @Paul sorry i'll add that to my question, I know z = 0 but what do I do wit $\ y = 4 - 2x $ ? Thanks for your reply!

Comment: So, can you think about a segment that goes from $(0,4,0) \to (2,0,0)$ ?

Comment: I guess that S is a triangle and you have to find the line segments where S meets the xy, yz and xz planes. Then the surface integral can be replaced with a line integral. Maybe - hard to say without knowing the intention of the question.

Comment: well it would just be a line segment wouldn't it? I've figured a little bit more see the edit